# Source compiled OpenSSL throws error "libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file" but it libssl.so.1.1 exists in ../lib?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, openssl

You can see below that when I attempt to invoke openssl without sudo on a source install ([instructions I followed](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/libraries/openssl/installation/installing_openssl_on_ubuntu_linux.php)), the command fails, but with sudo prefix it does not fail. When I try to check dependencies with ldd, I cannot get any meaningful info. What do I do to correct this?

Log:

```
toszter@odroid:/usr/local/openssl/bin$ sudo /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl 
/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
toszter@odroid:/usr/local/openssl/bin$ which openssl 
/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl
toszter@odroid:/usr/local/openssl/bin$ sudo openssl 
OpenSSL> ^C
toszter@odroid:/usr/local/openssl/bin$ ldd openssl 
    libssl.so.1.1 => not found
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6f47000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e5b000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f83000)
toszter@odroid:/usr/local/openssl/bin$ sudo ldd openssl 
    libssl.so.1.1 => not found
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6f10000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e24000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f4c000)
```

And before it is suggested, yes I saw [this post too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973267/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-1-1-and-libcrypto-so-1-1). Not a solution AFAIK.

Comment: Presumably `sudo openssl` is running the default `/usr/bin/openssl` (or whatever version it finds on sudo's `secure_path`) - rather than your source-built version

Comment: @steeldriver, no bc when I symlink /usr/bin/openssl to the source installed version, I get an epic fail too. Only in the log that I pasted is the scenario a success. Bizarre.

Comment: Seems I am most likely doing something I shouldn't be doing in the first place. This was a dependency of nmap which I found a debian package for in the debian package universe https://packages.debian.org/sid/nmap