# libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)

Tags: nginx, openssl

My server keeps running but suddenly jumps into error as

```
/usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to answer from a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218935/954174), but more specific to my issue of nginx:

```
/usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)
```

Mine issue could be caused by install other software that create "/usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0". It masks the real libcrypto.so.1.0.0 file.

**SOLUTION:**

1. I run `ldd /usr/bin/openssl`, then got:

   ```
   libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f1eb7e91000)
   libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f1eb7a36000)
   ```
2. These two files are wrong for nginx to run. So remove them as follows:

   ```
   /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
   /usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
   ```
3. Reboot machine, run `ldd /usr/bin/openssl` again, got:

   ```
   libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f40f5ee4000)
   libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f40f5a9f000)
   ```

SOLVED!

Debug process is inspired by [this blog](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_30507287/article/details/69389982)